# Integração entre Php e Word

Tags: php, html

É possivel realizar integração entre o php e word, pegar alguns valores de um campo de um determinado formulário e colocar no Word?. por exemplo em um formulário de contato tenha $nome , e se eu quiser coloca no Word $nome para que o word pegue esses valores.

Comment: Sim, é possível, basta você fazer o PHP gerar um arquivo que o Word reconheça.

Comment: Se você ainda não tentou nada da uma olhada no [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord). Se já tentou coloque mais detalhes na pergunta e inclua o código que você já tentou fazer e não funcionou.